# Rotating player towards their heading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to replicate a movement system from an old flash game I'm basing a game I'm making in unity on (just for practice, mostly.) The main problem I have is that the player doesn't 'look' towards where he is going. He just looks in the direction all the time.

[Here's what mine currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP1uD.jpg)

[and here's what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyQCa.jpg).

I've tried doing it but I couldn't find a solution that worked nicely (and the code for it is long gone). If someone could help me implement such a thing, that would be great!

The code for my player control:

```
public void PlayerFixedUpdate () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && transform.position.x > -44){
        if (body.velocity.x > -15){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(-15,0),ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && transform.position.x < 9){
        if (body.velocity.x < 15){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(15,0),ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && transform.position.y < 24){
        if (body.velocity.y < 15*body.mass){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(0,15),ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && transform.position.y > -1){
        if (body.velocity.y > -15*body.mass){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(0,-15),ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends how your object is set up, but one solution would be to set the rotation in the direction of the velocity component.

```
void rotateFace()
{
   Vector2 dir = rbody.velocity.normalized; // where rbody is your rigidbody2D
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90); //may not need 90deg offset here
}
```

You may want to include a check for zero velocity, in which case you should do nothing to maintain the last rotation.

Comment: Works fine, apart that it messes up the tail quite a bit. The individual parts start separating the more I rotate and move. Not parenting them directly to the player kind of worked, but the first tail part still becomes disjointed from the player.

Answer (score 0):

The second link shows like they are moving in one direction always and that is just the direction in which the character is facing, basically what they do is Just rotate the character using the player input and keep applying velocity in the local forward direction of the player.